# Why is my CSS not working now, it was working perfectly fine last night

Tags: html, css

My CSS file was working perfectly fine last night and I was able to apply any changes I want, but now I can't even change the background color or font of any elements in my HTML file. Please help me. I tried to make the body color black for example, but nothing changed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XYHG.png)

**HTML & CSS**

```css
body {
  margin: 60px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  font-family: Avantgarde, sans-serif;
  background: black;
}
header {
  background: gray;
  font-size: 2.0em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
#container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0.5px solid gray;
  padding: 25px;
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
input {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: left;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}
label {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: left;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}
#submit {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: left;
  width: 200px;
}
#login {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
#register {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Employee Management System
</header>
<div id="container">
  <div id="login">
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
      <h2>Fill out this form if you have an existing account</h2>
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="your username" required/>
      <br>
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required/>
      <br>
      <label></label>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="register">
    <form method="POST" action="register.php" class="form" onsubmit="return submitform(this)" id="myForm">
      <h2>Register Account</h2> 
      <label>First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="your first name" required/>
      <br>
      <label>Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="your last name" required/>
      <br>
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="your username" required/>
      <br>
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required/>
      <br>
      <label>Confirm Password:</label>
      <input type="text" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="password" required/>
      <br>
      <br>
      <span class="error"></span> 
      <br>
      <br>
      <label></label>
      <input type="submit" value="Register" class="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Head section looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Employee Management System</title>   
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
```

Comment: check your console did you get any error ?

Comment: @Ahmar css doesn't throw errors

Comment: I did't get any errors. And I obviously refreshed my page many times but nothing worked.. :(

Comment: Not refreshed, but did you clear your cache and refresh / CTRL+F5?

Comment: I cleared my browser's cache it finally worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An obvious answer, would be to clear your cache or just do `CTRL+F5`. If you're not too sure on how to clear your cache, have a look at this site.

http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home

Comment: Haha, great to hear. Browser caching can be a developers worst nightmare at times.